# how to fix this sharedpreference?

Tags: java, android

It is just a simple practice, but I need some helps with the `SharedPreferences`. Why it doesn't work.

Here is my java class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button display;
private EditText name;
private TextView text;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   final SharedPreferences  file = getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE);
   final SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = file.edit();
    display = (Button)findViewById(R.id.display);
   text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttext);
    display.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                String kk = name.getText().toString().trim();
                    editor.putString("username ", kk);
                    editor.commit();
                    text.setText(
                            file.getString("username","")
                    );
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

here is the catlog , I dont understand the exception. Can someone helps me explain it a little bit?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jinyu.practice, PID: 4573
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.example.jinyu.practice.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: If you just read the logcat, the error is very clearly not related to SharedPreferences :)

Comment: Simple case of an NPE....not a SharedPreferences problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate this: `private EditText name;`

Something like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //after this
name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

Comment: Oh, what a dumbed problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: @WuJinyu No issues, happens. Can you accept the answer btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

In your source code you are declare the EditText object but you are not 

initilise this EditText before you are geting the value using getText()

method so you get this NullPointerException Exception.

change like this

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button display;
private EditText name;
private TextView text;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   final SharedPreferences  file = getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE);
   final SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = file.edit();
    display = (Button)findViewById(R.id.display);
   text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttext);
   name== (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    display.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                String kk = name.getText().toString().trim();
                    editor.putString("username ", kk);
                    editor.commit();
                    text.setText(
                            file.getString("username","")
                    );
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```